# How to convert new 4x4 crawler to tracks?

Tags: technic, customization

With the new [9398](http://brickset.com/detail/?Set=9398-1) 4x4 crawler coming out what would need to be done to convert it to a track based system that looks similar in style to the ones sold by [Mattracks](http://www.mattracks.com/)?

On a related point what would make a good basis for making a Lego Technic model of the tracked buggies used in Prometheus that use similar 'track wheels'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I started with something based around the tracks that came with the original LEGO Mindstorm's kit: 680 Technic Tread:

[image: 680 Technic Tread]

I then build a rather more bulky than I'd have liked set of beams around it - I think if I'd have really dug out my Technic elements I'd have had more success making it look closer to the mattracks options:

[image: Full Unit]

Here's the very bulky rear - this would obviously want to be pared down somewhat, and you might want to either power the top wheel, or both the bottom ones:
[image: Possible gearing setup.]

Here's the rear with the beams removed:
[image: Rear beams removed]

You would need to have the driving axle on a universal joint to allow cornering, and would want to mount the whole thing on the mounts for steering.

I think it would be better if I'd had more of the newer Technic beams (the ones without the studs - I could have then connected them with two coat-hanger pieces and have another one vertically to the top.

Comment: Greate answer! I'd still like to see something that uses the 'tank' tracks that you get with various kits though (big digger, snow plough). Also it seems that Mattracks simple bolt to the hub where the wheel goes (probably with an adaptor plate) so I was expecting to simply slip any solution onto a shaft. Would that work?

Comment: @ClaraOnager I'll see if I can find any instructions for that model, and check the connections. I'll also try and dig out a few more bits of my Technic collection and have a better go at it ;) As to the other tracks, the end result would probably be similar, but you'd have a bit more control over the size due to the flexibility of the track sizes.